# How to group a list of commands to time them as a unit?

Tags: python

I have a long command saved in a file.
I also have a list of input files, which I want to pass to this same command,
so I have a `%s` specifier at two places.

```
$ cat https-tcp-session.txt

rm -f /tmp/A.raw /tmp/B.raw /tmp/result.raw; \
rwfilter --sport=443 --proto=6 --pass=stdout %s | \
rwsort --fields=sIP,dIP | \
rwgroup --id-fields=sIP,dIP --summarize | \
rwfilter --input-pipe=stdin --pass=/tmp/A.raw --packets=200-; \
rwfilter --dport=443 --proto=6 --pass=stdout %s | \
rwsort --fields=sIP,dIP | \
rwgroup --id-fields=sIP,dIP --summarize | \
rwfilter --input-pipe=stdin --pass=/tmp/B.raw --packets=200-; \
rwmatch --relate=1,2 --relate=2,1 \
/tmp/A.raw /tmp/B.raw /tmp/result.raw;
```

Next I try it on the python REPL.

```
>>> cmd = open('https-tcp-session.txt').read()
>>> cmd = cmd.replace('%s', 'trace.rwf.gz')
>>> time = '/usr/bin/time -f "%e"'
>>> stmt = '%s %s'%(time, cmd)
>>> os.system(stmt)
0.01 
0
```

That does not seem right.
For curiosity I put in an input file, and try to run it from the shell

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%e" bash https-tcp-session.txt
17.73
```

I have a feeling time is only timing the first command in the block (rm)

Comment: Did `os.system(stmt)` return `0` for success?  You've shown the output `0.01`, which I imagine is the output from the `time` utility, but `os.system(stmt)` returns the exit code of the subprocess it spawned, and when running it from the python REPL this value normally gets printed.

Comment: yes, os.system(stmt) returns 0. I have a feeling time is only timing the first command (rm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have suspected, it seems you are only running `time` on the first command in your `https-tcp-session.txt` file.  Your code in the Python REPL is sending something like the following to `bash` (or whichever shell you're using):

```sh
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" rm -f /tmp/A.raw /tmp/B.raw /tmp/result.raw; \
rwfilter --sport=443 --proto=6 --pass=stdout %s | \
rwsort --fields=sIP,dIP | \
# rest omitted
```

The semicolon at the end of the first line ends a command, so the shell runs `time` on `rm` only.

One possible fix would be to wrap your block of commands in a [group](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping).  That way, `time` runs on the group as a whole.

Alternatively, you could use [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters). You could replace the `%s` symbols in your `https-tcp-session.txt` commands with `$1`, which `bash` interprets as the first command-line argument.  You can then run `https-tcp-session.txt` as a shell script, passing the value to use in `$1` as the command line argument, for example:

```
$ bash https-tcp-session.txt trace.rwf.gz
```

(Please note that I haven't tested either approach.)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method:

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
# Do something
elapsed = time.time() - startTime
print("Elapsed time: %.3f" % elapsed)
```

When running timing functions for benchmarking purposes, it is best to run the programs/commands multiple times and take the average. So:

```
import time
elapsed = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_TRIALS):
    startTime = time.time()
    # Do something
    elapsed.append(time.time() - startTime)
print("Average elapsed time: %.3f" % (sum(elapsed) / float(len(elapsed))))
```

Comment: how much overhead am I adding when I am timing using python primitives?

Comment: It is actually quicker to do the timing in python than it is in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Always check return value from bash command, it should be 0.
Use subprocess module instead of os.system http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Print command before execute and try it in shell.

You can check timing using:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> some crazy comands
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> c = b - a
```